# Golang simplifying polyline data

Tags: go, douglas-peucker

I am pulling huge **geojson** datasets with golang, and I am wondering if there is anything like [simplify.js](http://%20https://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/) for golang, that would reduce the number of points in a polyline while retaining its shape?

https://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

Comment: You could translate the [source code](https://github.com/mourner/simplify-js/blob/master/simplify.js#L103-L113) to Go or use [a library](https://github.com/search?q=language%3Ago+Douglas+Peucker) that does the same. Not entirely sure though

Answer (score 1):

There is a Go port of simplify-js

https://github.com/yrsh/simplify-go